# PHP object loaded as reference in foreach loop

Tags: php, object, reference

I am looping through an object and i try to duplicate one of the items while changing one of it's variables.

But when i copy the original and then change the title in the new one, the old one changes along with it. Which it shouldn't, since i did not initialised it as a reference.

```
$calendar = array(
    (object)[
        'id' => 1,
        'title' => 'original 1',
    ],
    (object)[
        'id' => 2,
        'title' => 'original 2',
    ],
    (object)[
        'id' => 3,
        'title' => 'original 3',
    ],
);

foreach ($calendar AS $key => $item){
    if($item->id == 2){
        $item->title = 'new 2';
        array_splice($calendar, $key, 0, [1]);
        $calendar[$key] = $item;
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($calendar);
die();
```

I would expect the output of this to keep `original 2` intact. But it changes it along with it.

```
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [title] => original 1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [title] => new 2
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [title] => new 2
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 3
            [title] => original 3
        )

)
```

Even if i make a new object and use that one to make the changes, it still changes the orignial.

```
foreach ($calendar AS $key => $item){
    if($item->id == 2){
        $new_item = $item;
        $new_item->title = 'new 2';
        array_splice($calendar, $key, 0, [1]);
        $calendar[$key] = $new_item;
    }
}
```

Now i could probably fix this by just making a new object from scratch and copy the values one by one in it. But where's the fun in that?

So my question is...Why does this happen? Even though i didn't cast `$item` as `&$item`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As simple PHP Object assignment does not create a new object. It simply creates a new pointer to the same object.

I think you want to use the `clone` keyword:

```
foreach ($calendar AS $key => $item){
    if($item->id == 2){
        $new_item = clone $item;
        $new_item->title = 'new 2';
        array_splice($calendar, $key, 0, [1]);
        $calendar[$key] = $new_item;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

#### Assignment or clone ?

Because, you're using objects, the problem is that `$new_item = $item;` doesn't create a new object, it creates a **new reference** of `$item`, named `$new_item`.

In the following example, `$a` and `$b` are the same object:

```
$a = new stdclass;
$b = $a;
var_dump($a, $b);
```

Output is:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (0) {...} // same object #1
object(stdClass)#1 (0) {...} // same object #1
```

##### Clone

You could use the keyword [`clone`](https://www.php.net/clone) to create a new instance:

```
$a = new stdclass;
$b = clone $a; // Clone the object
var_dump($a, $b);
```

Output:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (0) {...} // object #1
object(stdClass)#2 (0) {...} // new object #2
```

##### So, in your case, you could use:

```
if ($item->id == 2) {
    $clone          = clone $item; // << Create a COPY of $item
    $clone->title   = 'new 2'; // Update the copy, not the reference
    $calendar[$key] = $clone; // Add this copy to final array
    // ...
}
```

#### A note about parameters

When you're using objects as parameters for some functions, objects are **reference**, so, the given object can be updated in that function. Here is a simple example ([demo](https://3v4l.org/1DXJT)):

```php
function updateObject(object $object): void {
    $object->newProperty = true;
}

$obj = new stdClass;
var_dump($obj);
updateObject($obj);
var_dump($obj);
```

The code above gives the following (condensed) output:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (0) { }
object(stdClass)#1 (1) { ["newProperty"]=> bool(true) }
```

Further reading : [Objects and references](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php)